# Why is the proxy not changed in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, webdriver

I wrote a python code and in this python code I feel that my proxy does not change

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep


#input proxy list
print("=======================================")
proxy = input("*\n-- please enter PROXY LIST: ")
print("*\n=======================================\n\n\n\n")

#open file list proxy
file_proxy = open(proxy,"r")

#loop proxy
for proxy in file_proxy:
    
    #set proxy
    PROXY = "<" + proxy + ">"
    webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
        "httpProxy": PROXY,
        "ftpProxy": PROXY,
        "sslProxy": PROXY,
        "proxyType": "MANUAL",
    }

    #sleep
    sleep(20)
```

example file list proxy:

```
91.98.80.2:8080
183.221.221.149:9091
103.134.177.182:8888
103.110.162.210:80
103.151.226.46:8080
165.154.235.178:80
120.196.186.248:9091
```

I am using Selenium library

And of course I know my code has an error, but I can't find it :/

Thank you for helping me

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, you should include what error message you get in your question. That would help us answer it :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't find any error and my only problem is that the proxy doesn't change.     Basically, the program runs well and Python doesn't show me any errors

You can test it to see what I mean ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DesiredCapabilities is deprecated](https://www.qed42.com/insights/coe/quality-assurance/selenium-4-deprecated-modified-and-new-methods). You can replace your code under `#set proxy` with:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```